# Set long table automatically to textwidth by changing font size

Tags: tables, margins, longtable, fontsize, textwidth

I have a 4 column Table that spans several pages. Thus, I use `longtable` as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=60mm, right=20mm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llll}
    \label{Table 1}\\ 
    \caption{Table 1}\\
    \makecell[tl]{A} & \makecell[tl]{B \\ C} & \makecell[tl]{D} & \makecell[tl]{E} \\
    Text 1 & Text 2 is really long which makes the table exceed the right page margin & Text 3 & Text 4
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

However, in this case the Table exceeds the right page margin. For short Tables I use resizebox, which works fine.

How can I automatically scale my table to textwidth? So, LaTeX shall automatically decreases the font size if there is a lot of text? I know that I should not scale tables but I think it makes the most sense in this case because I don't want to manually set the column width in cm values. Or, is it possible to scale each column relative to the page width as %-values?

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities  (and the syntax) of `longtable` to `tabularx`?

Comment: thanks! so I would use ```\tabularx``` instead of ```\longtable``` ?

Comment: using resizebox on tables does not "work fine" as has been commented on your earlier questions it should be done only as a last resort (and even then avoided)

Comment: Not exactly: replace `longtable{llll}` with  `xltabular{\textwidth}{lXll}` (if cells with long text are only in the second column, as in your example).

Comment: well, if  I do it as you suggested the table breaks the page width. Do you have a document that describes the column specifiers like X?

Comment: @nohomejerome:  Using `xltabular` as Bernard described should not result in a table that exceeds the textwidth. If it does, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.